# UWP: Registering an in-process background task fails with "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: c#, uwp, background, task

I want to run an in-process background task and so use the following code to try and register it. As per the documentation from Microsoft, for an in-process background task you do not provide a TaskEntryPoint, as it will call the application method App.OnBackgroundActivated instead when it needs to run.

```
await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = "Background Ping";
builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
builder.Register();
```

It fails on the Register call with "Value does not fall within the expected range". I cannot see anything that is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you check the `Note` section on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task#register-your-background-task-trigger)?`Universal Windows apps must call RequestAccessAsync before registering any of the background trigger types. To ensure that your Universal Windows app continues to run properly after you release an update, you must call RemoveAccess and then call RequestAccessAsync when your app launches after being updated. `

Comment: Yes, I actually tried calling RemoveAccess before the RequestAccessAsync each time so I do not think that can be the issue.

Comment: If so, please provide a [mcve]. I need to test it on my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the error is caused by trying to allow multiple instances of the application. I had added the following attribute to the **Application** tag in the **.appxmanifest**

```
desktop4:SupportsMultipleInstances="true"
```

This is a relatively new attribute used to indicate your UWP application can have multiple instances. So starting the UWP app causes new instances instead of simply moving focus to the existing running instance. As an Enterprise application I need to support multiple instances. Seems you cannot have in-proc background tasks. Guess I am stuck with using an out-of-process task and handle the pain that is communicating with it.